# Ajax jQuery working fine in localhost XAMPP but not Working in hpanel of hostinger

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ajax jQuery working fine in XAMPP but whenever I do upload in hpanel of Hostinger it doesn't work. please check my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).on('submit', '#ajax-form', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var formData = new FormData(this);
        formData.append("comment", true);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "postcomment.php",
            data: formData,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (response) { 
                location.reload(true);                    
            }
        });

    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I do not see any problem in the code, probably an error is shown in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing in console. for that you have to open your browser's inspect element. you can do it by pressing ctrl + shift + I. you might get error in console too if there is some. you can paste your ajax code over there. Also if it that doesn't work check your network tab once. you will surely get some hint what's wrong from your side.